# Ubuntu's gcc implies `-fPIC` but openSUSE does not, is it affected by some configuration file or what?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, opensuse

Lab environments:

- Ubuntu 18.04, gcc 7.5.0, binutils 2.30 (2019-05-08)
- openSUSE Leap 15.5, gcc 7.5.0, binutils 2.39 (2022-10-25)

I realize this problem when building a small .so file from `foo1.c` .

```c
#include <stdio.h>

extern void FooX(int);

void Foo1(int i)
{
        printf("foo1(%d)\n", i);
        i++;
        FooX(i);
}
```

On openSUSE, compile it using commands:

```
gcc -g -c foo1.c

gcc -shared foo1.o -o libfoo1.so
```

The second command fails with error message:

> ld: foo1.o: relocation **R_X86_64_32** against **`.rodata'** can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

[image: opensuse linking .so error message.]

As suggested by above `ld` error message. I go back and do `gcc -g -c -fPIC foo1.c`, then `ld` succeeds.

But on Ubuntu 18.04, I do not have to explicitly assign `-fPIC` to gcc.

[image: Ubuntu build .so success]

So, on openSUSE, the `foo1.o` must have different machine code when it lacks vs has `-fPIC`.

I make some effort to compare them on openSUSE.

```
gcc -g -c foo1.c
mv foo1.o foo1-noPIC.o

gcc -g -c -fPIC foo1.c
mv foo1.o foo1-PIC.o

objdump -dSlr -M intel foo1-noPIC.o > foo1-noPIC.txt

objdump -dSlr -M intel foo1-PIC.o > foo1-PIC.txt
```

Below is the difference between `foo1-noPIC.txt` and `foo1-PIC.txt` :

[image: Compare -fPIC no vs yes]

I also do this on Ubuntu, and `foo1-noPIC.txt` and `foo1-PIC.txt` have same content, and they equal openSUSE's `foo1-PIC.txt`.

Now, I confirm that Ubuntu's gcc implies `-fPIC` for us.

Then, my question is, **is such difference hard codeded into a Linux-distro's gcc binary, or, is it affected by some configuration file on a Linux distro?** If latter, which configuration file?

Comment: The phrase you're looking for regarding GCC configuration is "specs", sometimes "specs file".

Comment: An Ubuntu gcc *can* behave different from a stock gcc. Ubuntu gcc-7.5.0 : **164** `files.diff` http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-7/gcc-7_7.5.0-6ubuntu2.diff.gz ..... "opensuse leap 15.5" gcc-7.5.0 : **52** `files.patch` https://ftp.lysator.liu.se/pub/opensuse/distribution/leap/15.5/repo/oss/x86_64/gcc7-7.5.0+r278197-4.30.1.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 0):

As you've noticed, some Linux distros build their GCC compilers with `-fPIC` as
a default option, which you must override with `-no-fPIC` if you don't want it; other distros
build with `-no-fPIC` the default, which you must override with `-fPIC`<sup>1</sup>.

> Then, my question is, is such difference hard coded into a Linux-distro's gcc
> binary, or, is it affected by some configuration file on a Linux distro?

Yes, it is hardcoded and No, it is not affected by any configuration file on a linux distro.
However, you can always vary the default and non-default options by feeding a suitable
configuration file of your own into your `gcc` commands. I'll demonstrate this by
switching my own stock Ubuntu `gcc` from default PIC to default no-PIC.

**Spec strings and spec files**

The [GCC manual: 3.20 Specifying Subprocesses and the Switches to Pass to Them, para. 1](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html#) explains:

> gcc is a driver program. It performs its job by invoking a sequence of other programs to do
> the work of compiling, assembling and linking. GCC interprets its command-line parameters
> and uses these to deduce which programs it should invoke, and *which command-line options it
> ought to place on their command lines*. *This behavior is controlled by spec strings*. In most
> cases there is one spec string for each program that GCC can invoke, but a few programs have
> multiple spec strings to control their behavior. *The spec strings built into GCC can be overridden by
> using the* -specs= *command-line switch to specify a spec file.*

(my emphasis)

**Parsing the built-in specs**

`gcc` uses its built-in specs by default:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
...[cut]...
gcc version 13.2.0 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-4ubuntu3)
```

I can extract the built-in specs to a file like this:

```
$ gcc -dumpspecs > gccspecs.txt
```

If you do that, you will see that `gccspecs.txt` is a file of daunting
goobledegook, but the documentation already referred to teaches you how to
read it (though not easily).

I see that the only spec-string in which `fPIC` is mentioned is the one for
spec-name `cc1`. This spec-name represents a subset of the arguments that will
be passed the (real) C compiler - also called `cc1` - that `gcc` calls to do C-language compilation.

```
*cc1:
%{!mandroid|tno-android-cc:%(cc1_cpu) %{profile:-p};:%(cc1_cpu) \
%{profile:-p} %{!mglibc:%{!muclibc:%{!mbionic: -mbionic}}} \
%{!fno-pic:%{!fno-PIC:%{!fpic:%{!fPIC: -fPIC}}}}}
```

(line-continuations `\` - and any sort of comments - are not valid spec-string syntax.
I pretend otherwise to avoid triggering horizontal scroll.)

Eek. Let's tease this out in pseudo-code, where:

- *input S* will mean *S is specified in the* `gcc` *options*
- *output S* will mean *append S to the expansion of* `cc1`.
- A reference of the form `%(specname)` will mean *the expansion of spec-name* `specname`.

It says:

```
If (not input `-mandroid`) or (input `-tno-android-cc`) {
    output `%(cc1_cpu)`
    If input (`-profile`) {
        output `-p`
    }
} else {
    output `%(cc1_cpu)`
    If input (`-profile`) {
        output `-p`
    }
    If (not input `-mglibc`) {
        If (not input `-muclibc`) {
            If (not input `-mbionic`) {
                output `-mbionic`
            }
        }
    }
    If (not input `-fno-pic`) {
        If (not input `-fno-PIC`) {
            If (not input `-fpic`) {
                If (not input `-fPIC` {
                    output `-fPIC`
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which is logically equivalent to the more concise:

```
If (not input `-mandroid`) or (input `-tno-android-cc`) {
    output `%(cc1_cpu)`
    If input (`-profile`) {
        output `-p`
    }
} else {
    output `%(cc1_cpu)`
    If input (`-profile`) {
        output `-p`
    }
    If (not input ( `-mglibc` or `-muclibc` or `-mbionic`)) {
        output `-mbionic`
    }
    If (not input (`-fno-pic` or `-fno-PIC` or `-fpic` or `-fPIC`)) {
        output `-fPIC`
}
```

And if we disregard everything not relevant to the `-f[no-](pic|PIC)` options<sup>2</sup>,
that can simplify further to:

```
If (input `-mandroid`) and ( not input `-tno-android-cc`) {
    If (not input (`-fno-pic` or `-fno-PIC` or `-fpic` or `-fPIC`)) {
        output `-fPIC`
}
```

This reveals that my `gcc`, by default, will react to the absence of all `-f[no-](pic|PIC)`
options only in case it is targeting android and it has not been
told to rule out an android compiler. In that case, it will react to the absence of
all `-f[no-](pic|PIC)` input options by outputting `-fPIC` to the compiler. If on the other hand:

- it is not targeting android (no `-mandroid`), or
- it has been told to rule out an android compiler (`-tno-android-cc)`, or
- any of `-f[no-](pic|PIC)` has been input,

then `gcc` outputs just the same `-f[no-](pic|PIC)` options as were input, including none.

Let's confirm that:

```
$ cat foo.c
#include <stdio.h>
void foo(void)
{
    puts("Hello World");
}
```

Without input `-mandroid`, without input `-f[no-](pic|PIC)`, I expect no `-f[no-](pic|PIC)` output at all:

```
$ gcc --verbose -c -o foo.o foo.c 2>&1 | egrep -oh cc1.*\(pic\|PIC\); echo Done 
Done
```

Without input `-mandroid`, with input `-fPIC`, I expect `-fPIC` output:

```
$ gcc --verbose -fPIC -c -o foo.o foo.c 2>&1 | egrep -oh cc1.*(pic|PIC); echo Done 
cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu foo.c -quiet -dumpbase \
foo.c -dumpbase-ext .c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -version -fPIC
Done
```

With input `-mandroid`, without input `-f[no-](pic|PIC)`, I expect `-fPIC` output:

```
$ gcc --verbose -mandroid -c -o foo.o foo.c 2>&1 | egrep -oh cc1.*(pic|PIC); echo Done  
cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu foo.c -mbionic -fPIC
Done
```

With input `-mandroid`, with input `fno-PIC`, I expect `fno-PIC` output:

```
$ gcc --verbose -mandroid -fno-PIC -o foo.o foo.c 2>&1 \
| egrep -oh cc1.*\(pic\|PIC\); echo Done  
cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu foo.c -mbionic -quiet -dumpdir foo.o- \
-dumpbase foo.c -dumpbase-ext .c -mandroid -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -version -fno-PIC
Done
```

That all checks out.

**Overriding the built-in specs with a specs file**

In the absence of any of the relevant options, I can see that my `gcc` defaults to PIC code if
I dump its predefined macros:

```
$ echo | gcc -dM -E - | egrep -h .*(__pic__|__PIC__)
#define __pic__ 2
#define __PIC__ 2
```

So I'm assured that I can successfully build a shared library from `foo.c` with
without `-fPIC`:

```
$ gcc -c -o foo.o foo.c
$ gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o
```

and indeed I did:

```
$ file libfoo.so
libfoo.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, \
BuildID[sha1]=3e5aaafab114a7de260f0c2da16b6f58bb81e5e1, not stripped
```

And for that to fail I have to perversely try:

```
$ gcc -c -fno-PIC -o foo.o foo.c 
$ gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o
/usr/bin/ld: foo.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: failed to set dynamic section sizes: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Suppose however I would like to flip my `gcc` so that:

- With `-mandroid` input , without `-f[no-](pic|PIC)` input, I get `-no-fPIC` output, instead of `-fPIC`
- Without `-mandroid` input, without `-f[no-](pic|PIC)` input, I get `-no-fPIC` output, instead of nothing.

i.e. With or without `-mandroid`, without `-f[no-](pic|PIC)` input, I will get `-no-fPIC` output. The compiler will
default to absolute code, not position independent.

Reworking the `*cc1` pseudo-code to that end makes it:

```
If (not input `-mandroid`) or (input `-tno-android-cc`) {
    output `%(cc1_cpu)`
    If input (`-profile`) {
        output `-p`
    }
} else {
    output `%(cc1_cpu)`
    If input (`-profile`) {
        output `-p`
    }
    If (not input `-mglibc`) {
        If (not input `-muclibc`) {
            If (not input `-mbionic`) {
                output `-mbionic`
            }
        }
    }
}
If (not input `-fno-pic`) {
    If (not input `-fno-PIC`) {
        If (not input `-fpic`) {
            If (not input `-fPIC` {
                output `-no-fPIC`   // instead of `-fPIC`
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That is just a matter of:

- replacing the one and only `output -fPIC` with `output -no-fPIC`,
- hoisting the `pic/PIC` stuff out of the scope of the `{...}` that enclosed it.

Applying that change to the `*cc1` spec string looks like so:

```
*cc1:
%{!mandroid|tno-android-cc:%(cc1_cpu) %{profile:-p};:%(cc1_cpu) \
%{profile:-p} %{!mglibc:%{!muclibc:%{!mbionic: -mbionic}}}} \
                                                       #  ^ Add `}` here  \
%{!fno-pic:%{!fno-PIC:%{!fpic:%{!fPIC: -fno-PIC}}}} \
                                               #   ^ Delete `}` here \
                                     #  ^ `fPIC` -> `fno-PIC`
```

The whole new string goes in a spec file:

```
$ cat specfile.txt 
*cc1:
%{!mandroid|tno-android-cc:%(cc1_cpu) %{profile:-p};:%(cc1_cpu) %{profile:-p} %{!mglibc:%{!muclibc:%{!mbionic: -mbionic}}}} %{!fno-pic:%{!fno-PIC:%{!fpic:%{!fPIC: -fno-PIC}}}}
```

Which I can use as follows.

With `-mandroid`, without `-f[no-](pic|PIC)` input, I now expect `-no-fPIC` output:

```
$ gcc --verbose -mandroid -c -o foo.o foo.c -specs=specfile.txt 2>&1 \
        | egrep -oh cc1.*(pic|PIC); echo Done
cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu foo.c -mbionic -fno-PIC
Done
```

Without `-mandroid`, without `-f[no-](pic|PIC)` input, I now expect `-no-fPIC` output:

```
$ gcc --verbose -c -o foo.o foo.c -specs=specfile.txt 2>&1 \
        | egrep -oh cc1.*(pic|PIC); echo Done
cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu foo.c -fno-PIC
Done
```

Feeding `specfile.txt` to `gcc` has the expected effect of undefining the
built-in macros `__pic__` and `__PIC__`

```
$ echo | gcc -specs=specfile.txt -dM -E - | egrep -h .*(__pic__|__PIC__); echo Done
Done
```

So with my spec file I've flipped `gcc` from default `-fPIC` to default `-no-fPIC`. Which
means of course linkage failure when object files compiled
without `-fPIC` are input to a `-shared` linkage:

```
$ gcc -c -o foo.o foo.c -specs=specfile.txt
$ gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o
/usr/bin/ld: foo.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' \
    can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: failed to set dynamic section sizes: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Can you make** `gcc` **search for a spec file?**

Yes and No...

No, `gcc` won't search for spec file unless you specify a spec file
with the `-specs` option. That's the sense in there's no "configuration file"
that will do the job if you just install it.

Yes, in the sense that if you do specify `-spec=`*specfile*, then `gcc` will search for a file with precisely the
terminal name element *specfile* (even if it has path components) in the same places that it would search
for the toolchain files it requires, such as its programs and libraries, and failing all those it will search the current directory. So if you really wanted to, you could create
a subdirectory `specs`, under, say `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/<version>`, put a repertoire of spec files
in there *spec0*,...,*specN*, and have `gcc` select one of them by passing `-specs=specs/`*specJ*. Note
that if you specify `specs=`*specfile* and `gcc` can't find it, it gives a fatal error; it doesn't fall back
on the built-in specs.

**Spec files for portability magic?**

Wouldn't it be cool to use a spec file to iron out the default behavioural differences between
the `gcc` that your source package build finds on target system *A* and the one it finds on target
system *B*? It could obviate the need for some of the thorny conditional logic
in your package build files.

I think not. To craft a dependable spec file you would need to know exactly the differences in default
behaviour that you had to iron out in all possible cases - the same knowledge you need to craft dependable
build files that don't involve spec files. Hard as it is to craft dependable build files, it's even
harder to craft a dependable spec file. And more important, the competence to debug a buggy build file
is widespread amongst source package consumers and vastly more common than spec file expertise.

Indeed, dependable build logic means not depending on `gcc`'s default behaviour. There's always an option that
explicitly mandates or prohibits a behaviour trait *F* if that is the right thing in any supported build case.
You need to know whether to mandate or prohibit *F*, for each supported build case, and logically arrange
that the build specifies the correct option. Best to keep all this in plain sight to the utmost practical
extent, in the build files and in their console output. Using spec files would be an obfuscatory approach.

---

1. This schism started in 2013, when Debian moved to default PIC.
2. There is a fine technical distinction between `-f[no-]PIC` and `-f[no-]pic` but it's irrelevant here.